# Why doesn't DroboElite mount all my volumes?

Tags: windows, mount, drobo

I am using a DroboElite with 8 hard drives, connected over the LAN using the iSCSI protocol. I have defined several volumes (2 x 2TB, 1 x 4TB and 1 x 8TB) and mapped drive letters to each of them (no CHAP used).

Whenever my Windows 7 x64 workstation restarts, the Drobo consistently does not mount the largest of my volumes (the 8TB has about 5TB of data on it); I always have to open the Drobo Dashboard and manually tick the *Mount* check-box.

Has anybody encountered the same problem with the Drobo? How can I prevent this from happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest version (2.1.2 at the time of this writing) of the Drobo Dashboard solved the issue. I should have tried this first...